# uninitialized constant file in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My test folder is structured like this:

```
  test
    models
      restaurant
        helpers
           employee.rb
        points_test.rb
```

So my `PointsTest` looks like this:

```
require 'models/restaurant/helpers/employee.rb' 

   class Restaurant::PointsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
     ....
     employee1 = Restaurant::Employee.create
```

And the file `Employee` like this:

```
class Restaurant::Employee
   def self.create
     .....
```

**Everything works like this**

**---------------------------------------------**

Now i tried to change `class Restaurant::Employee` to `class Restaurant::Helpers::Employee`

and in `PointsTest` i changed to `employee1 = Restaurant::Helpers::Employee.create`

And I get **this error**:

**uninitialized constant Restaurant::Helpers (NameError)**

What do I wrong? I mean `Helpers` is in the subfolder `helpers`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t just **declare** constants in chain like `A::B::C::D` since each constant is to be looked up.

```
module Restaurant
  module Helper   # declare module Helper
    class Employee
      ...
```

would work. While

```
                # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ fail on try to const_get(:Helper)
class Restaurant::Helper::Employee
```

fails on constant `Helper` lookup, since it’s not defined. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks it worked! And is there a way to shorten the `module`-declarations. Is there a way to put it in one Line?

Comment: Of course `module Restaurant ; module Helper ; class Employee` with respective closing `end ; end ; end` works. But generally using this is not a best practice. I would declare `module Restaurant::Helper ; end` and then use your initial short notation, which is now fine since the module was already defined.